# How to Inject a new Class to Overridden Class using Preference

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager

I want to override `__prepareLayout` function from 'Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History' so I used the preference.

In my `di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" type="Custom\Module\Block\Order\History"/>
```

In my `History.php`

```
class History extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->setTemplate('Custom_Module::order/history.phtml');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

To this point my code is working fine now I want to inject custom Helper in this class.

So I added this-

```
    public function __construct(
        \Custom\Module\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper   =   $helper;
    }
```

After Injecting Class the code is not working. I have the option to use `ObjectManager`, but it is not recommended, so I preferred to ask from Community if you have any better Option!

Comment: What is the error showing if you added helper in contruct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call parent constructor also with required parameters

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
    \Custom\Module\Helper\Data $helper
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
    $this->helper   =   $helper;
    parent::__construct($context, $orderCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $orderConfig);
}
```

Comment: Correct solution. But should this be overridden since its an API class which means it should not be updated.

Comment: yes this is correct solution +1